# How to set ulimit in Ubuntu 15.10 chroot?

Tags: 15.10, chroot, ulimit

I have an Ubuntu 15.10 in a chroot and would like to permanently set a ulimit value (ulimit -c unlimited). I have looked at modifying the /etc/security/limits.conf file but the changes are not being taken into account. Changing those files need a logout or reboot and being in the chroot makes that impossible I believe. Community please what is your advice?